# Google Analytics 4 Consent Mode: update status and fire tag

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, google-talk, cookieconsent

need a piece of advice/solution regarding `GA4 Consent Mode`.

A few CMS systems have installed their own `Consent Plugins` with their advantages and disadvantages.
But with the same principle - they block cookies and scripts till they receive user *consent*.
So, after the *consent* is given I wanted to update tags with this JS code:

```
<script>
    gtag('consent', 'update', {
      'ad_storage': 'granted',
      'analytics_storage': 'granted'
    });
</script>
```

It seems that this approach doesn't work well on some environment - *consent* is not always updated.
But there is a main problem with **non Google Tags**.

The **Facebook tag**: I've set rule for "Require additional consent for tag to fire to `ad_storage` "
Storage status is updated in *Consent layer* but *FB* tag is not fired. It seems, that the update process should be done earlier...
Any thoughts? Any JS solution?
[image]